# Backup sump pump AND primary pump backup battery?

Tags: basement, sump-pump

I recently bought a house where the previous owners had the whole basement flood because the power went out and they had no backup sump pump.

Prior to selling, they tore up all the floors and put in a secondary battery powered backup pump. Thing is, I’ve tested it by dumping water into the sump pit and it works…sometimes. The float switch is cheap and doesn’t seem to always work.

So my thought is to buy a battery backup for the main pump, then leave the battery backup as an absolute last resort. Is this overkill? If not, would it make sense to get a 2000 watt or a 1500 watt backup?

Comment: Probably be cheaper to get a small generator.  No need to worry about the battery die if you have enough gas.  Might be some other things you want to have power in a black out.

Comment: I had one or two good back-up batteries for the back pump. At some point you can only let it rain; what will be, will be.

Comment: I'd replace the float switch on the backup pump  before doing anything.

Comment: Is the soil your home is built on just very well-draining?  You've done all you can to make water in the vicinity leave on the surface?

Comment: Yeah, I did fix a lot of the drainage issues that the previous owners had.  I'm fairly confident that drainage is fine I'm just paranoid that the power will go out or something while we're away from home.


Generator isn't a bad idea but, i'd want something that'd automatically kick in during a power outage.  


Replacing the float switch might help but i also think it's just super cheap and not well designed.

Comment: That's the problem. Most 12V sump pumps are cheap Cheese junk.  You might actually be better off using a 120V sump pump fed by an inverter off the battery.  Inverters have a nasty standby load, so get an inverter that has a port for a remote startup/shutdown signal. Run that through a sump pump limit switch, so the inverter only runs when the pump needs to run.

Comment: you could use a float switch to switch AC to the real sump, or to connect an inverter so that you don't have the high standby load of an inverter 24x7. You might need to use a relay if the float switch current isn't higher than your pump draw.